# Вывод из базы данных шести наибольших значений?

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести из базы данных шесть самых больших значений? 
Почему то вот это не работает и выводит в виде?

```
555553
422154
35355353
300
1234134
123412
```

Вот код, который осуществляет выборку

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `DBTop` ORDER BY `col_vo` DESC LIMIT 6";
$TOP = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($TOP) > 5){
  while($sTOP = mysql_fetch_assoc($TOP)){
    echo $sTOP['col_vo'] . "<br />";
  }
} else {
   echo 'лол';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше поле "col_vo" представляется как текстовое (по-моему, даже, и varchar). Запрос адекватен, вот только текстовые поля MySQL сервер сортирует по алфавиту (кодовом значении символов), где "5555" меньше за "6" и "9" больше за "1111".

Обратите внимание на первые цифры (символи):
**5**55553 **4**22154 **3**5355353 **3**00 **1**234134 **1**23412

Задайте полю тип данных integer и будет Вам счастье :)

Comment: упс мой пробел забыл про это